# Spring Boot Add Query Parameter Into the Select Statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have a query like so (which i put one of the parameters of the method into the DTO projection):

```
@Query("SELECT new com....dto.SomeDTO(x.id, x.name, :abc) FROM SomeEntity x WHERE x.property = property")
List<SomeDTO> getSomething(@Param("property") String property, 
                           @Param("abc") String abc);
```

---

And when i try to run the program i get the error:

```
Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com....dto.SomeDTO]. Expected arguments are: int, java.lang.String
```

It seems like jpql is ignoring the parameter passed into the DTO.

---

However if i wrap the param value with jpql `concat` it works. Like so:

```
@Query("SELECT new com....dto.SomeDTO(x.id, x.name, CONCAT(:abc, '')) FROM SomeEntity x WHERE x.property = property")
List<SomeDTO> getSomething(@Param("property") String property, 
                           @Param("abc") String abc);
```

---

Here is the SomeDTO:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeDTO {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  public SomeDTO(Integer id, String name, String parameter) {
    if ("something".equals(parameter)) { //doSomething }
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

what is happening here, why does the second one works but not the first. Should i keep doing like the second one or is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Show us the code of `SomeDTO`

Comment: @lucumt i added the dto.

Comment: Can you add this property in your config file `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and add in the question what is the 'SQL' that is being triggered onto the database in both cases.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor It already exists in propertiy file. The problem is when i try to run the program it gives the error above. So it doesn't run any query. It says it couldn't find the appropriate constructor at the beginning(when building the program).

Comment: if there's no property 'abc' on the entity, I guess the resulting query from jpa will ignore it. So there are only 2 params left and there's no matching constructor. So use your workaround...